# Databricks dbx deploy error with authentication token

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-dbx

I'm trying to deploy a new workflow using the dbx cli from Databricks, when i'm running:

```
dbx deploy new_workflow
```

I'm receving the following error:

```
Exception: Provided configuration is not based on token authentication.Please 
switch to token-based authentication instead.
```

I already authenticated with databricks-cli so i'm a little bit lost on what to do next

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already fetched dapi token from Databricks user settings -> Access token section. Then, please check that the name of your profile matches the profile name in your dbx project.

Databricks CLI config in the file `~/.databrickscfg`

```
[your-profile-name]
host = <workspace-URL>
token = <token>
```

Dbx configuration in `your-repo/.dbx/project.json` file

```
{
    "environments": {
        "default": {
            "profile": "your-profile-name",
            "storage_type": "mlflow",
            "properties": {
                "workspace_directory": "/Shared/dbx/my_project",
                "artifact_location": "dbfs:/Shared/dbx/projects/my_project"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, ensure that *your-profile-name* is spelt the same in both files and has required access to create or update workflow in your Databricks workspace.

Then, your `conf/deployment.yml` file should look something like this.

```
build:
   no_build: true

environments:
  default:
    workflows:
      - name: "new_workflow"
        tasks:
          - task_key: "some_task"
            notebook_task:
              notebook_path: "/some/notebook/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you are facing issue with sufficient access permissions to perform task.

Reference: https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth.html